# Converting .TPS (TopSpeed) to SQL

Tags: odbc

I have an older application that uses TopSpeed as the database engine. I want to use some of the data contained in these tables in another application that uses SQL. To accomplish this, I purchased the TPS ODBC driver and used Access to move the data from the TPS tables to an SQL database by using the linked tables feature.

This works fine, but I'm looking for an automated solution (plus, the Access way is messy). Is there a tool out there that could help?

Comment: Why do you need automation, is the data being updated on the old system?

Comment: Yes. We have production software using this database, and the software I need to interface with it speaks SQL, so I have to migrate the data on a regular basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use Access as a mediator.

You can look into SSIS or import utility to import data from .TPS to SQL. You have to select Flat file data source.

At the end of the import utility, you will have the option to save the package and then schedule it using SQL Agent job.

Refer to : [How to Migrate Data From Top Speed Database Files](https://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/02/sql-server-how-to-migrate-data-from-top.html)

Also, look into [SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssma/migrating-data-into-sql-server-using-ssma). I have used it for Sybase to SQL Migration, but not sure if it will be good fit for TopSpeed migration.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm looking for a more automated method, though. SSMA doesn't support TPS.

Comment: @NathanC best is to use SSIS for automation.

Comment: Thanks, I think SSIS will be the best method. Something new to learn. It's either that or writing my own program which I don't have the time to do.